# selects, joins, & wheres in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to select specific columns from two tables however when I add the ->select() method into my query, I get an error.

If I leave out the ->select() method, I get a valid resultset and everything works, but adding the select breaks it. Sadly the error reported has nothing to do with the query and is useless to me.

Here is the code that works:

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
           ->join('notifications_pivot', function($join)
         {
                $join->on('notifications.id', '=', 'notifications_pivot.notification_id')
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.user_id', '=', Session::get('id'))
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.is_read', '=', 'N');
        })
         ->get();
```

Now here's the code that breaks:

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
        ->join('notifications_pivot', function($join)
         {
                $join->on('notifications.id', '=', 'notifications_pivot.notification_id')
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.user_id', '=', Session::get('id'))
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.is_read', '=', 'N');
        })
                   ->select(DB::raw('notifications.id, notifications.subject, notifications.message, notifications.url, 
                                notifications.start_date, notifications.end_date, notifications.access_role_id, notifications_pivot.id,
                               notifcations_pivot.notification_id, notifications_pivot.user_id, notifications_pivot.is_read'))
         ->get();
```

It's times like these when I wish I could just write straight SQL and parse the query!
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `DB::raw()` and just pass the fields you want as parameters.

If that doesn't work, the Laravel log at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` may provide more insight.

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
        ->join('notifications_pivot', function($join)
         {
                $join->on('notifications.id', '=', 'notifications_pivot.notification_id')
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.user_id', '=', Session::get('id'))
                     ->where('notifications_pivot.is_read', '=', 'N');
        })
        ->select('notifications.id', 'notifications.subject', 'notifications.message', 'notifications.url', 'notifications.start_date', 'notifications.end_date', 'notifications.access_role_id', 'notifications_pivot.id', 'notifcations_pivot.notification_id', 'notifications_pivot.user_id', 'notifications_pivot.is_read')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Yes I tried that first, but Laravel throws the same useless error, so that's why I tried the raw select.

Comment: Btw, the error is


Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tells me nothing about why the query failed, err, why Laravel failed to properly construct the query...

Comment: I think the query is probably running fine, but you're having an exception thrown when passing the data to your view.  Wrap a `dd()` around the whole query and see if it dumps it in your controller.  If it does, then the issue isn't with your query and we should look at the way you're passing it to your view instead.

Comment: The view loads just fine if I leave the select method out. I've tried logging the query with Log::error() but because Laravel crashes, the query never gets logged. That being said, I'm pretty sure the data in the view is fine, the problem is getting the data to the view, err getting the data I want to the view with the select method.

Comment: So it turns out that I had a typo in my select statement. I was missing an i in 'notifications_pivot'. The sad thing is that Laravel's error wasn't useful. If it had been a straight PHP error then I would have known there was something wrong with the query, although I knew there was something wrong with the select method I added in anyway. I have seen this behavior before in Laravel. Most of the time Laravel's error reporting is very helpful, but this particular to_string() error is a known issue. Hopefully they'll fix that one of these days.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked out for you.  I make lots of typos :) but  I've found that in MySQL `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` provides more info if you think there is a problem with the query and Laravel isn't returning a MySQL error.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. It's almost always some stupid little typo!  :-)